# Book about an object that turns things around it (a barn, grass, a horse) into black crystals or glass

Tags: story-identification, books

From what I remember, the main character somehow finds out about this object (I believe it was a meteorite) and goes to find it. The grass around it has been crystallized and a horse, or maybe a mule, that's been crystallized somehow shambles towards the main character, and eventually falls into a pit and shatters. IIRC, the object is eventually destroyed or neutralized by something involving magic a bridge, but that part is fuzzy.

Does anyone recognize these details?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, I'm not sure what you meant by this part of your description: _"involving magic a bridge"_ Could you clarify?

Comment: I read a story similar to this in an anthology of classic Weird Tales fiction. The plot followed an artist who traveled to a jungle to capture an alien life-form that turned everything it touched into black crystal. Not all of your details match this story.

Comment: @LogicDictates Sorry about that, what I meant was that the meteorite was deactivated or destroyed using magic/witchcraft and it had something to do with an old bridge. Again, that part is fuzzy, so I'm not quite sure if that's exactly how it was resolved. I read this in 2018 or 2019, but I can't remember when it may have been published, but the copy I read didn't seem too old, maybe 90s or 2000s. The part of the book with the horse had a tone shift to horror instead of the sort of mystery of the rest of the book. IIRC the MC was a young girl living in a small country town.